# Does nature tetrate?

Tags: mathematics, nature

We see addition, multiplication and exponentiation in the natural formulae that make up physics.

However, do we ever see [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) (repeated exponentiation) or higher hyper-operators in nature?

(Not counting cases where the tetration step could be trivially eliminated.)

Comment: Tetration generally leads to extremely large numbers, which aren't very useful (except perhaps on the largest (or smallest) scales).

Comment: This strikes me as such an arbitrary question.  Blackbody radiation is proportional to $T^4$ which you could view as $T^{2^2}$

Comment: @BrandonEnright - Edited Q to exclude trivial cases of tetration. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simple" functions you mentioned are often the result of solving "simple" (differential) equation. Repeated exponentiation is a very uncommen solution, however I do know of repeated exponentiation in formulae, often to scale dimensionless parameters.